# Optimizing frequently called function with large local variables (C++)

Tags: c++, optimization, stack-memory, static-memory-allocation

Let's say there is a function that I need to call millions of times. Arithmetic operations performed by this function are not so heavy, so the only thing that matters is how fast all variables are allocated. Also we assume that the variable is always allocated on stack.
The simplest case example:

```
void doSomething(){
    int aReallyLargeVariable[10000];
    ...performing a few light operations on that variable and returning nothing...
}
```

I know that when function returns all it's variables are destroyed,so
wouldn't it be better to cache this variable by making it static or global? What would be the best way to optimize it?

Comment: Make the variable a parameter of the function and use the same variable for many function calls?

Comment: Is the function called recursively or concurrently?

Comment: And - since you're already aware of alternative designs, can you share your benchmark results on the comparisons you must surely already have run?

Comment: As with any performance issue - check the generated code / profile it / actually check what it's doing. I am guessing that the compiler will generate the same code in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the allocation that will cause performance problem. The problem is to initialize it so when

```
    int aReallyLargeVariable[10000];
```

won't take many time the

```
    int aReallyLargeVariable[10000] = {0};
```

will do. Also creating huge objects dynamically can cause a problem.

If you have a function that has not very heavy logic and is using only primitive types just define it as `inline` and do not worry about performance.

If you need to define big amount of object think about another data structure like `stack` or `vector` that won't need to have 1000 or more elements

Answer (score 1):

To optimize this function, considering it is called many times, the first step would have to be `do not declare the large variable locally`. When you do that, a few things happen:

- a lot of stack space is wasted, since you declared the array locally and probably only use a few values.
- the stack operations (push/pop) caused by this declaration probably outweigh the actual work the function has to do.

You are better off declaring this array somewhere else (declare it globally if you have to) and pass in a pointer to the array. This way you can also reuse the memory and not waste time reallocating.

Comment: As m.antkowicz says, the time needed for the stack operations themselves (push/pop) is not affected by the size of the local variables; these operations just change a register value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to allocate them as static so that the entire  `int aReallyLargeVariable[10000];`wont bother the stack by allocating and deallocating this huge amount of memory every time the function is called. However, you can also declare the `int aReallyLargeVariable[10000];`
as global, but many developers hate a lot of global variables in their code. If you don't like static variables in functions (due to concurrent execution or so) and don't like global variables either, then you can declare the variable as static in the global scope so that the variable name only be valid in the context of its declaration which can prevent linker errors.

**Source.cpp**

```
static int aReallyLargeVariable[10000];
void myFunction()
{
    aReallyLargeVariable[1] = 10;
}
```

**Object.cpp**

```
int aReallyLargeVariable[10000];  /* No name collisions during linking */
```

Note: It only works as long as you don't decide to include the **Source.cpp** in **Object.cpp** or vice verse